# Finding boundary points of (-infinity, a) where a is rational in the space of rational numbers with usual topology

Tags: general-topology

"In the space of rational numbers with the usual topology (the subspace topology of $\Bbb R$), the boundary of $(-\infty,a)$, where a is irrational, is empty."

There are many ways to find boundary points like $A \subseteq X$:

1. $\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$
2. $\operatorname{cl}(A)\cap \operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$

But i am using the definition that a point is a boundary point if its every open neighborhood contains some points of the set and some points outside of the set.
I feel like $a$ in $(-\infty, a)$ should be  boundary point as any open neighborhood ( by subspace topology open sets will be                                      $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon) \cap \Bbb Q$ of $a$ will contain some points of $(-\infty, a)$ and some outside of it. But i am not getting where I am wrong as they say that the set has no boundary point.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So $a\notin\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ can only be a boundary point of $A=(-\infty, a)$ in $\Bbb Q$ when $a$ is a member of $\Bbb Q$ in the first place! The set $A$ is a set of rationals (!) and its closure and interior points are also subsets of the rationals, because that is the "universe" we're considering. So you cannot consider neighbourhoods of a point, that's not even in your space at all!

The "mean" thing here is that the set is defined in terms of a point $a$ that is *not* in $\Bbb Q$ but in $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$. But this makes $A$ closed and open at the same time in $\Bbb Q$ because $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb Q}(A)= \operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}(A) \cap \Bbb Q = (-\infty,a] \cap \Bbb Q = A$.

So $\partial A= \operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)=A\setminus A=\emptyset$.

Comment: I did not understand how closure of A is A because A is an interval (-infinity, a),where a is a irrational number and its intersection with Rationals will only give the rationals in that interval

Comment: @KajalNegi The set $A$ is really $\Bbb Q \cap (-\infty, a)$, all rationals that are $< a$ (in $\Bbb R$, where $a$ is defined). It can also be seen as $\Bbb Q \cap (-\infty, a]$, which is clearly closed in $\Bbb Q$.